# Firebase, React CRUD: Deleting a document by document ID

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My component `UniqueVenueListing` displays a list of live music performances(gigs). 
 A complete list of gigs is brought in via an axios request in the `GigRegister` component and passed as props to `UniqueVenueListing`, where they are mapped over and rendered to the browser.
I want to add delete functionality, so that logged in users can delete specific gigs. 
Here's what I've done so far: In `UniqueVenueListing`, I wanted a real time subscription to database changes, so I included the following request:

```
const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('gig-listing')

const getGigs = () => {
    ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const items = []
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            items.push(doc.data())
        })
        setGigs(items)
    })
}
```

I then wrote a function to perform the deletion -

```
const deleteGig = () => {
    ref
    .doc(//some variable representing the specific doc id of a gig)
    .delete()
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
    })
}
```

and finally I've got the button pointing to this delete function:

```
const button = <StyledButton onClick = {()=> {deleteGig(//some passed in gig)}}>Delete Gig</StyledButton>
```

So I've got all the 'bits', I just don't know how to tie them all together to produce a deletion. I want to be able to delete gigs based on gig ID, which I know can be retrieved from the getGigs function - console.log(doc.id) yields the IDs). Here's the entire component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Giglisting from './Giglisting'
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import firebase from 'firebase'

const StyledButton = withStyles({
    root: {
      background: '#54ADA6',
      borderRadius: 3,
      border: 0,
      color: 'black',
      height: 30,
      padding: '0 30px',
      marginRight: '1px'
      
    },
    label: {
      textTransform: 'capitalize',
    },
  })(Button);


const UniqueVenueListing = (props) => {
const gigList = props.gigList
const [gigs, setGigs] =useState([])


const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('gig-listing')

const getGigs = () => {
    ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const items = []
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            items.push(doc.data())
        })
        setGigs(items)
    })
}

useEffect(() => {
    getGigs()
},[])

const deleteGig = () => {
    ref
    .doc(gigs.id)
    .delete()
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
    })
}

const button = <StyledButton>Delete Gig</StyledButton>

    return(
        <div>
          {
              gigList.map(gigs => {
                 return <Giglisting
                 gigtitle = {gigs.name}
                  genre = {gigs.genre}
                  time = {gigs.time}
                  buytickets = {gigs.tickets}
                  button = {button}
                  />
              })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default UniqueVenueListing
```

Here's the part of the `GigRegister` component that filters and sends data to `UniqueVenueListing`:

```
      authListener() {
        auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
            this.setState(
              {
                userDetails: user
              },
              () =>
                axios
                  .get(
                    "https://us-central1-gig-fort.cloudfunctions.net/api/getGigListings"
                  )
                  .then((res) => {
                    let filteredGigs = res.data.filter((gig) => {
                      return gig.user === this.state.userDetails.uid;
                    });
                    this.setState({
                      filterGigs: filteredGigs
                    });
                  })
            );
          } else {
            this.setState({
              userDetails: null,
            });
            console.log("no user signed in");
          }
        });
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.authListener();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem starts in your `` function, where you are extracting the **data** of each document, but are ignoring the document IDs that you need later. You'll want to change that function to get both the data and the ID for each document:

```
const getGigs = () => {
    ref.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
        const items = []
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            items.push({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() })
        })
        setGigs(items)
    })
}
```

With that you can then render both the data *and* the ID in your render method, and then pass the ID along to `deleteGig`.

Comment: That's helpful - but I think I've found the root of my issue. Could I get your opinion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64364855/firebase-react-changing-a-get-request-from-get-method-to-onsnapshot-method