# Firebase, React: Changing a GET request from get() method to onSnapshot() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-router

I've written a function that gets data from my firestore, filters through it, and returns data posted **only** by the logged-in user. The data, in this case, are gig listings:

```js
      authListener() {
        auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          if (user) {
            this.setState(
              {
                userDetails: user
              },
              () =>
                axios
                  .get(
                    "https://us-central1-gig-fort.cloudfunctions.net/api/getGigListings"
                  )
                  .then((res) => {
                    let filteredGigs = res.data.filter((gig) => {
                      return gig.user === this.state.userDetails.uid;
                    });
                    this.setState({
                      filterGigs: filteredGigs
                    });
                  })
            );
          } else {
            this.setState({
              userDetails: null,
            });
            console.log("no user signed in");
          }
        });
      }
```

However, when I render this data, I want it to be subscribed in real time to database changes, and I also want to be able to access the document id. In order to do this, I want to change this function to use the `onSnapshot()` method, here's my (rough) attempt:

```js
authListener() {
    auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
    this.setState(
    {
        userDetails: user
    },
    () =>
    firebase.firestore().collection('gig-listing').onSnapshot(querySnapshot=> {
    let filteredGigs = querySnapshot.filter(gig => {
        return gig.user === this.state.userDetails.uid;
        })
    })
    this.setState({
        filterGigs: filteredGigs
        });
    })
);
```

This code isn't working and I have a feeling there's more than one issue, but the main error I'm getting back is `querySnapshot.filter is not a function`. Can anyone suggest how to re-configure my code so I can use the snapshot method, instead of my axios get request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

querySnapshot is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) object.  As you can see from the API documentation, there is no method `filter` on that object.  If you want something to filter, perhaps you meant to use its [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) property, which is an array of [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) objects that contain the actual document data.  So, maybe something more like this is what you want:

```
let filteredGigs = querySnapshot.docs.filter(snapshot => {
  return snapshot.data().user === this.state.userDetails.uid;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take aa look at the docs, the `onSnapshot()` method returns a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot). The `QuerySnapshot` has a `docs` property which has all the documents in the snapshot. So you can filter them like this :

```js
firebase.firestore().collection('gig-listing').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => querySnapshot.docs.filter(d => {
  const data = d.data()
  // Do whatever with data
})
```